# DeckSwiper native-base nothing render

Tags: react-native, native-base

I use DeckSwiper from '[native-base](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#deckswiper-def-headref)'

I don't understand why nothing is render

```
renderAd = (item, index) => {
        console.log(item)
        return <Text key={index}>{item.adress} </Text>
    }

    search() {
        return <DeckSwiper ref={(c) => this._deckSwiper = c} dataSource={tabAd} renderItem={this.renderAd}/>
    }
```

I am sur DeckSwiper enter in renderAd (console.log(item)) display in console.

Tanks.